# Multiply the same sides of two inequalities

Tags: inequality

I have two inequalities ($a,b,c,d,e > 0$):
$$\begin{array}{lcl}
a & \le & b \\
\frac{1}{c} & \le & \frac{d}{e}
\end{array}
$$
why it is correct to consider the product of the element on the same side?
$$ \frac{a}{c} \le b \cdot \frac{d}{e}$$
Please, can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: Are $a,b,c,d,e$ positive?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this axiom of real multiplication inequaities:

If $a > 0$ and $x \le y$, then $ax \le ay$
In your case, we have:

$\frac{1}{c} > 0$, so since $a \le b$, then $$\frac{a}{c} \le  \frac{b}{c}$$.

Furthermore, $b > 0$ and $\frac{1}{c} \le \frac{d}{e}$. Hence, $\frac{b}{c} \le b \frac{d}{e}$

Apply the transitivity of inequality to get the conclusion.
I hope this has answered your question.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe some intuitive explanation. 
You have something like:
$$l_1 < r_1 \wedge l_2 < r_2 $$
If all of them are positive, you can look at that like:
something smaller $\times$ something another smaller < something bigger $\times$ something another bigger

Comment: Does this property have a name? Can you send me a link to a documentation about it?

Comment: @JB-Franco - it is rather an intuitive approach than formal proof.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true in general indeed from

$$A\ge B \iff A-B\ge 0$$

$$C\ge D\iff C-D\ge 0$$

then we can deduce only that

$$(A-B)(C-D)\ge 0\iff AC+BD-AD-BC\ge 0$$

which is different from

$$AC\ge BD$$

For example

$$4\ge -4\quad \land \quad 1 \ge -2 \quad \not \Rightarrow \quad 4\ge 8$$

It is always true that

$$A\ge B\quad \land \quad C\ge D\implies AC\ge BD$$

when all the terms are positive since in that case we have

$$AC\ge BC\ge BD$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a alternate way to proceed:

$0\le a\le b\implies u=b-a\ge 0$

$0\le \frac 1c\le \frac de\implies v=\frac de-\frac 1c\ge 0$

Now if we multiply the quantities:

$b\times \frac de = (a+u)(\frac 1c+v)=\frac ac+(\underbrace{av+\frac uc+uv}_{\ge 0})=\frac ac+w\quad $ with $\quad w\ge 0$

Since all quantities, $a,c, u, v$ are positive, then $w$ is positive too.

$$\frac {bd}e-\frac ac=w\ge 0\iff \frac ac\le\frac {bd}e$$

Note: we implicitly used these two propertiesto show the positivity of $w$:

- $x\ge 0$ and $y\ge 0$ then $x+y\ge 0$
- $x\ge 0$ and $y\ge 0$ then $xy\ge 0$